# Stereo matching with one camera

Tags: opencv, point-clouds

I'm looking into stereo matching to build a point cloud from two photos with OpenCV.

Will it work correctly if the images come from just one pinhole camera, that has been moved/rotated? Will I pass the same calibration parameters to stereoRectify (will I need to use that function)?

Comment: what you're looking for is called 'structure from motion',  not stereo calibration

Comment: Hey @berak, I've tried to compile the example without success, you can see the log here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20821444/compiling-a-pcl-example-on-mavericks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the question is clear enough.

1. Are you trying somehow to infer motion from subsequent images? If yes, you could take a look at **Optical Flow**.
2. If you want to detect objects you could check Scale Invariant Feature Transform (**SIFT**). It doesn't depend on affine transformations, scaling or rotations.
3. If you're trying to take a set of images so that you could perform a sort of matching, you'll need to know the **focal distance** of the camera and also the **baseline** (this would be the distance between left and right camera - in your case the position of camera for first image, and position for the second one).

Hope it helps.